# Drawing suspended while processing async NSURLConnection receive data

Tags: ios, drawing, nsurlconnection, nsthread, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I'm loading data from a server and processing the response asynchronously. Using NSURLConnection. Each call to the delegate, connection:didReceiveData: is processing that chunk.

However, right before a big chunk of data is received, I requested a text view to scroll to a new line, ie [textView scrollRangeToVisible:].

The problem is that often, the textView does not scroll until all the data have been received. This can be a while and makes the UI look hung.

To attempt to work around it, I was thinking the main thread is locked up processing the data, so I should break it up into smaller chunks.

So I changed to code to break up the data received in connection:didReceiveData to perform smaller operations, and queued them up using

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:smallerChunk waitUntilDone:FALSE]
```

The thinking being that it puts a bunch of events on the runloop and would handle the scrollRangeToVisible as it could.

However this isn't working. At least not reliably.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"However this isn't working. At least not reliably." is a pretty vague error description. However, I would suggest that you process the data received from the connection in a background thread so that it will not block the main thread.

You can for example create a serial dispatch queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and in `connection:didReceiveData:` submit the processing of the data to that queue:

```
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    /* process data */
});
```

Comment: At least not reliably meant that sometimes it does get around to scrolling the text view, but often at the end or close to end of processing the data. Its so slow its not useful. I've tried your approach and it worked. My concern had been that I'm populating a Core Data database with the received data and worried about accessing it from a background thread. However, there's no access going on from any other thread during this process so it might be safe. I don't recall if Core Data restriction is that a MOC can only be used on one thread at a time, or just one thread period.

Comment: @David: I'm glad to hear that my suggestion helped you. (Don't forget to accept the answer.) - There are indeed strong restrictions on how a MOC can be used on different threads. You will find a lot of postings on that topic here on SO. If you need more help, I would suggest that you  start a new question, as this is a completely different topic.